# Why does an event handler output all of its actions at the same time?

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, events, event-handling

I want that when the button is pressed, two numbers one are displayed with an interval of half a second in textbox

But if you do everything as in my example, both numbers are displayed simultaneously in half a second

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Checker.Text += "1";

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

            Checker.Text += "1";
        }
```

The same will happen with any loop inside any event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Thread.Sleep() call will block the Dispatcher thread. Its that thread that updates your UI, in order to do what you want you will need to either run a background worker thread, or more simply use the Async/Await syntax

```
  private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Checker.Text += "1";

        await Task.Delay(500);

        Checker.Text += "1";
    }
```